# Tkinter window title as a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to dynamically change the window title based on the data being displayed in the window.  I display a window with a selected weather alert.  In the window title, I want to put the alert event name.  Each selected alert will have its own event name.

I created a small test to show using a variable in the title works.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mytitle='MYTITLE'
root.title(mytitle)
root.mainloop()
```

However when I apply what I think is the same setup in my popup window I get title "PY_VAR0".

```
def msgwindow(x):
    print('in message window')
    alert_info = Toplevel(root)  # Child window
    alert_info.geometry("600x700")  # Size of the window
    alert_row = alert_tree.item(alert_tree.focus())  # selected value to display

    alert_row_title = tk.StringVar()
    alert_row_title.set(alert_row['values'][1])
    print('value1:', alert_row['values'][1], 'title:', alert_row_title)
    alert_info.title(alert_row_title)

    alert_row_value = tk.StringVar()
    alert_row_value.set(alert_row['values'][4])

    alert_label = tk.Label(alert_info, textvariable=alert_row_value, justify=LEFT)
    alert_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+W)
```

I added a 'print' which shows my title variable has the intended value but the same variable used in title shows PY_VAR0

value1: High Surf Advisory title: PY_VAR0

The the data in alert_row_value displays as intended.  This must be simple...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `alert_info.title(alert_row_title.get())` work? It seems like `alert_info.title()` might only accept a `str`, not a `StringVar`. The documentation would probably make that clear though.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay I'll add that as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert_info.title()` requires a `str`, not a `StringVar`. So, you need to use `alert_row_title.get()` to get a `str` that you can pass in. So, your code just needs to be:

```
alert_info.title(alert_row_title.get())
```